# Automatic flushing in java.io.PrintWriter and java.io.PrintStream: when is it appropriate?

Tags: java, java-io

The default setting for automatic flushing is `false` for both `java.io.PrintWriter` and `java.io.PrintStream`. So it would seem that automatic flushing is only for specific use cases.  What would some of these be?  And what would be some cases where one would specifically avoid automatic flushing?

Comment: You might turn off flushing when you want to control when the data is flushed, eg. to improve performance.

Comment: I'd put it the other way around. I would only turn it *on* when you're writing to the console, or to a file that absolutely must have the latest logged event in it on a crash, or maybe when you're writing lines to a Socket that are acted on line by line by the peer (although you shouldn't use PrintStream/Writer over a network at all). Otherwise I would turn it off.

Comment: Thanks both of you, I can see situations where either of these could apply.  @EJP sorry to continue in another direction but could you say more about why we should avoid `PrintStream/Writer` over a network?  Very interested in this - thx!